# Error accessing AzureDevOps build pipelines even though User is a contributor

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am an administrator to a DevOps project and i have full access to the project.

I am trying to provide a user whom i only need to give access to a certain pipeline.

Steps Take:

Initially i provided him with only Reader access and he is not able to access the URL (404 error)
I removed him from reader and provided with Contributor access and still cannot access the pipelines.
Getting below error,

404 - Page not found Looks like this page doesn’t exist or can’t be found. Make sure the URL is correct. 23/05/2022 2:48:04 PM (UTC) 1e9217ce-2731-4aaa-b853-80c7444299e8

Like i said, the user is a member of the Valid Users and Contributor built-in roles without any customization.

The user is able to navigate to releases and environments and deployment groups, but not able to access build pipelines, library, or Task groups.

Error screen and screenshots attached

[image: project home screen]
[image: Error screen]
[image: permissions]

Comment: What is the access level of the user inside the organization?

Comment: I am an administrator of the project and my Organization access level is Basic. The User i am trying to give access to have StakeHolder access.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for stakeholders? The answer to your question is there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/stakeholder-access?view=azure-devops#azure-pipelines

Comment: As we have tried at our end with private project and getting 401 error, `stating that we don't have access`. And after inviting/Adding user to the project user can able to access . Make sure that the `url` which provided to the user is in correct format . So Could you please let us know, do you need assist on access level like how to invite or add user to access the `url` of your project even if its private project. or something else..? [MS DOC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/provide-stakeholder-pipeline-access?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) .

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved after i contacted microsoft. The issue was due to the user access is stakeHolder. Thanks for  GeralexGR comment i was able to streer through that direction.

Resolution:
Change users access level from StakeHolder to Basic. [image]